# How does the Maximal Eigenvalue of the Prime Index Matrix behave?

Tags: matrices, prime-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I had a look at the eigenvalues of the matrix, I called it Prime Index Matrix (is there a better name?), constructed like the following:
$$
P_{k,p_k}=P_{p_k,k}=1,
$$
where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime. $P$ is symmetric and for $k_\max=6000$ looks like the left figure:

[image]
[image]

The maximal eigenvalue behaves strange, since from time to time I get bumps, which I can't explain (see right figure). The largest value I got was $1.9021$ for $k_\max=6000$. Is it possible to show that the eigenvalue never exceeds $2$ (or less)?

> How does the Maximal Eigenvalue of the Prime Index Matrix behave?

**EDIT**

The bumps appear at
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{prime} & \max \lambda\\ \hline
2 & 1\\
3=p_2 & \sqrt{2} \\
5=p_3 & \phi\\
11=p_5& \sqrt{3}\\
 31=p_{11}& \frac16 \left(\sqrt[3]{-28+84\sqrt{3}i}+ \sqrt[3]{-28-84\sqrt{3}i}+2\right)\\
 127=p_{31}& \sqrt{2+\sqrt 2}\\
 709=p_{127}& \frac12 \left( \sqrt[3]{4+4\sqrt{3}i}+\sqrt[3]{4-4\sqrt{3}i}\right)\\
 5381=p_{709}& \frac12 \sqrt{10+2\sqrt{5}}
\end{array}
$$

**EDIT2.0** The values above were easy to get analytically once you know how they are generated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evaluation of the maximal eigenvalue can be reduced to a system of equations like the following:
$$
\pmatrix{
     0&1&0& &0&0&0\\
     1&0&1&\cdots&0&0&0\\
     0&1&0& &0&0&0\\
&\vdots&&&&\vdots\\
0&0&0&&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&\cdots&1&0&1\\
0&0&0&&0&1&0\\
}\cdot\vec v -\lambda \vec v=0
$$
(s. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/691940/19341))
Let's look at it as an adjacency matrix of a graph, i.e. the line graph.
When the dimension of this system grows to infinity, we could identify this with a closed graph, the cycle graph, a $2$-regular graph. And we know that the degree of a regular graph is the maximal eigenvalue of the adjacency matrix.

This answers my main question: The maximal eigenvalue never exceeds $2$.

It is left to show how the values actually grow. Here's a plot of $\log_2 \lambda_\max$:
[image]